# Reorganize a grid at breakpoint with a different order - html css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reorganize

I'm sorry if my question look simple, but i'm stuck in a project and i think i missed something to make it work good.

I've to do a div reorganisation at breakpoint 1024px.

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Xkp.jpg)
How can i use flexbox to put the child 3 right side of child 1 and 2 ? 
I've tried with flexwrap but actually, i'm not sure that is the good way.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You would be better off using `display: grid` there

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i check grid display on mdn ;)

Comment: Remember that `display: grid` is CSS not JS.

Comment: Well, i'm looking the best solution, i made some search and my real problem is more to put right colomn at center. i make a try with reorganization, may i just use flex box in parent and width 50% in child, float: left for child 1 and 3 and float right for child 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-column-gap: 10px;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            height: 500px;
            max-width: 1024px;
        }

        .div1 {
            grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
            background-color: brown;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .div2 {
            grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: burlywood;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .div3 {
            grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: coral;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="div1"> DIV1 </div>
        <div class="div2"> DIV2 </div>
        <div class="div3"> DIV3 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you,

i found the best way with grid, thanks carlos.

My parents is now :

```css
.result-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: size col1 size col2;
    grid-template-rows: size row1 size row1;
    grid-template-areas:
    "child1 child2"
    "child3 child2";
    height: 500px;
}
```

My child are assign with grid-area: child1;

I have learn to assign grid-area that is really hard to understand at first for me.

Thanks ;)